# Concatenating strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called `img1` and it is equal to `image.jpg`.
I want to concatenate the variable `img1` with url, brackets and quotes so i get 
`"url(image.jpg)"` with the quotes as another variable, say `picture`. Then, i can use

```
document.getElementById("id_of_some_element").style.backgroundImage=picture;
```

where `picture` is `url(image.jpg)` with quotes, i.e. `"url(image.jpg)"`
It is important that i concatenate the `img1` variable and not `image.jpg` directly because `image.jpg` can change based on the user's input.

Comment: The `+` operator concatenates strings in JavaScript.

Comment: not to mention that if you put the title of this question into google you would find all sorts of results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var picture = "url(" + img1 + ")";
```

Read the manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

May be you want something like this :

```
var picture = 'url(' + img1 + ')';
document.getElementById("id_of_some_element").style.backgroundImage=picture;
```

**?** You don't really need quotes as for CSS "url(image.jpg)" and url(image.jpg)  - is the same.